# How to silence the "video capture device" popup?

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, startup

I am developing an android program using eclipse and the emulator and each and every time, when I start the emulator I get a popup asking me for the video capture device. The app that I am developing has absolutely nothing to do with video, so I definitely don't give a $#!@ whether the emulator has acess or uses my laptop's built-in camera or not. How can I silence this annoying startup question?

Michael